# Small method that runs various processes

Tags: c#

I have a project which runs from a db table - it's purpose is to run processes written in various ways.

Currently it deals with python scripts, vbs scripts and console exe files.

It works but I'm wondering if there any obvious refactors?

```
private Process aProcess;

public void runProcess(string aPath,string aName,string aFiletype)
{

  aProcess = new Process();
  string stInfoFileName = null;
  string stInfoArgs = null;
  bool blUseShell = false;


  //if it is to call a python script
  if(aFiletype == "py")
  {
    stInfoFileName = @"python.exe";
    stInfoArgs = string.Format("\"{0}{1}{2}\"",aPath,Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,aName);
  }

  //if it is to call console app exe
  if(aFiletype == "exe")
  {
    stInfoFileName = aName;
    stInfoArgs = string.Format("\"{0}{1}{2}\"",aPath,Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,aName);
    blUseShell = true;
  }

  //if it is to run vbs script
  if(aFiletype == "vbs")
  {
    stInfoFileName = "cscript";
    stInfoArgs = string.Format("/B \"{0}{1}\"",@aPath,@aName);
  }



  aProcess.StartInfo.FileName = stInfoFileName;
  aProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = stInfoArgs;

  aProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = aPath;           //<< does not seem to need the extra quotes

  aProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = blUseShell;
  aProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;

  aProcess.Start();

  this.aProcess.WaitForExit();
  this.aProcess.Dispose();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd first start with naming conventions. Prefixes are usually avoided and method name is PascalCase:

```
public void RunProcess(string path, string fileName, string fileExtension)
```

Honestly I'd accept just one parameter with full path and I'd split it inside this method but you might not be able to change this then I won't comment about it.

First I'd extract a method to create the `StartupInfo` leavinig in this method only invocation and parameters validation:

```
if (path == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));

// More validations...

using (var process = Process.Start(CreateStartupInfo(path, fileName, fileExtension)))
{
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Then, moving to `CreateStartupInfo()` implementation, I'd first drop those `if` in favor of a `Dictionary` or a plain list because it's much easier to extend and it might come from a configuration file (no need to change code to support more file types.)

For the moment keep the if in-place but consider:

- Do not perform string comparison with `==`. It's a current culture aware case sensitive comparison, it's not obvious and it's not probably what you want. Use `String.Equals()` specifying the right `StringComparer`/`StringComparison` value.
- Do not manually build paths, there is `Path.Combine()` for that. Let's see an example where for simplicity I have as input the full file path.

Given this *holder*:

```
sealed class KnownFileType
{
    public KnownFileType(string type,
        bool useShellExecute,
        Func<string, string> interpreter,
        Func<string, string> interpreterCommandLine)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public string Type { get; }
    public Func<string, string> Interpreter { get; }
    public Func<string, string> InterpreterCommandLine { get; }
    public bool UseShellExecute { get;  }
}
```

We can declare a list of known file types like this (note that his can be outside the method and static):

```
var fileTypes = new KnownFileType[]
{
    new KnownFileType(".py", false, x => "python.exe", x => $"\"{x}\""),
    new KnownFileType(".exe", true, x => Path.GetFileName(x), x => $"\"{x}\""),
    new KnownFileType(".vbs", false, x => "cscript.exe", x => $"/B \"{x}\""),
};
```

Do you need to add new known file type? Add one line here. If those values come from a configuration file then you might want to use `String.Format()` instead (be careful if configuration can be tampered.) Because I dislike escape sequences I'd introduce an helper method:

```
private static string Quote(string text) => '"' + text + '"';
```

Using it I may *simplify* above code to:

```
new KnownFileType(".py", false, x => "python.exe", x => Quote(x))
```

To create the `ProcessStartupInfo` you just need to:

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(fullPath);
var fileType = fileTypes.First(x => String.Equals(x.Type, extension, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

return new ProcessStartInfo
{
    UseShellExecute = fileType.UseShellExecute,
    FileName = fileType.Interpreter(fullPath),
    Arguments = fileType.InterpreterCommandLine(fullPath),
    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath)
};
```

Note that here I used a plain array but if you opt for a `Dictionary<string, KnownFileType>` (with the proper case insensitive comparer for keys) then code may be slightly simplified to:

```
var fileType = fileTypes[Path.GetExtension(fullPath)];
// ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Before even considering refactors, I think there's a bug.

> ```
>   //if it is to call console app exe
>   if(aFiletype == "exe")
>   {
>     stInfoFileName = aName;
>     stInfoArgs = string.Format("\"{0}{1}{2}\"",aPath,Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,aName);
> ```

Why call `foo.exe "path\foo.exe"`? I can think of *very* few situations in which an exe should take its own name as a command-line argument.

---

I'm also unconvinced by the general structure. Why should your program have to take care of mapping file types to executors? That's functionality that's built into the operating system. If the registry is correctly configured then the method should just be

```
public void RunProcess(string aPath, string aName, string aFiletype)
{
  using (var aProcess = new Process())
  {
    aProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(aPath, aName);
    aProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = aPath;
    aProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    aProcess.Start();
    aProcess.WaitForExit();
  }
}
```

Comment: do you use the parameter `aFiletype` in your `RunProcess` method?

Comment: I am simply using the path to the copy of the exe file that resides in the bin folder - it is not deployed anywhere. So in the sql control table that I query to find out which process is next I have for example "solution\debug\bin\foo.exe". Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Something else that you may be able to take advantage of is String Interpolation, but that depends on which version of C# you are currently using.

By using String Interpolation you can get rid of the call to `String.Format` and replace the placeholders with the actually object that you want inserted into the string.

This

> ```
>   if(aFiletype == "py")
>   {
>     stInfoFileName = @"python.exe";
>     stInfoArgs = string.Format("\"{0}{1}{2}\"",aPath,Path.DirectorySeparatorChar,aName);
>   }
> ```

Becomes this

```
if(aFiletype == "py")
{
    stInfoFileName = @"python.exe";
    stInfoArgs = $"{aPath}{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}{aName}";
}
```

Which looks a lot cleaner, in my opinion.

---

I also noticed that you are calling a `.Dispose()` Method which tells me the `Process` object implements the [`IDisposable` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) and this interface allows you to use a [`using` statement block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).  You can keep it from closing the application in the same way that you are currently doing it by calling the `WaitForExit()` method as the last command before closing the `using` block.

The benefit of using a `using` block is that even if there is an error the process will be disposed of and the memory will be released.

Upon further research it appears that the [Process Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) Inherits the [Component Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component(v=vs.110).aspx) which implements the [IDisposable interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: (upped) thanks for your help Malachi. So many suggestions working out which has been most useful will not really be very objective choice.

Comment: point taken about `IDisposable` - I will switch to a `using` clause structure.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing which I would approve in this code - it's extensibility. Currently each time you add support to new file type, you have to open source code of your application, modify it, compile and only then you can use it. Same goes to modifying runner associated with file type, or changing format of args passed to process. I would made this part configurable on the fly. E.g. with xml or json config file:

```
<runners>
 <runner fileTypes=".py" path="python.exe" argsFormat="${dir}\${file}" />
 <runner fileTypes=".exe|.bat" path="${file}" argsFormat="${dir}\${file}" useShell="true"/>
 <runner fileTypes=".vbs" path="cscript" argsFormat="/B &quot;{dir}{file}&quot;"/>
</runners>
```

Note that I have added support of several extensions to single runner. Then I would create runner class which would use all these settings:

```
public class ProcessRunner
{
    public IEnumerable<string> SupportedExtensions { get; set; }
    public string RunnerPath { get; set; }
    public bool UseShell { get; set; }
    public string ArgsFormat { get; set; }

    // behavior goes here
 }
```

You can also add some validation for these properties, or create them as read-only (assigning values via constructor). So, we have all data in place. Only behavior is left

```
public void Run(string path)
{
    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(path);
    var comparer = StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase;
    if (!SupportedExtensions.Contains(fileExtension, comparer))
        throw new NotSupportedException($"File type {fileExtension} is not supported.");

    using (Process process = new Process())
    {
        process.StartInfo = BuildStartInfo(path);
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
}

private ProcessStartInfo BuildStartInfo(string path)
{
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    var file = Path.GetFileName(path);
    var keywords = new Keywords().Add("dir", dir).Add("file", file);

    return new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = keywords.Replace(RunnerPath),
        Arguments = keywords.Replace(ArgsFormat),
        WorkingDirectory = dir,
        UseShellExecute = UseShell,
        RedirectStandardOutput = false
    };
}
```

Simple as that. Now we need someone to create runners and pick them according to file type passed. You can build some specific xxxConfiguration file, but I believe it's OK to create runners directly from xml

```
var configFile = "runner.config";
var runners = from r in XDocument.Load(configFile).Root.Elements("runner")
              select new ProcessRunner
              {
                  RunnerPath = (string)r.Attribute("path"),
                  SupportedExtensions = r.Attribute("fileTypes")?.Value
                     .Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries),
                  ArgsFormat = (string)r.Attribute("argsFormat"),
                  UseShell = (bool?)r.Attribute("useShell") ?? false
              };
```

Now prepare dictionary with fileType-runner mapping (you can add validation here as well to check whether some fileTypes are mapped to several runners):

```
var runnersByFileType = runners
  .SelectMany(r => r.SupportedExtensions, (runner, fileType) => new { runner, fileType })
  .ToDictionary(x => x.fileType, x => x.runner, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

And running your files will look like:

```
ProcessRunner runner;
var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(path);
if (!runnersByFileType.TryGetValue(fileExtension, out runner))    
    // handle not supported fileType case

runner.Run(path);
```

Comment: Note: I believe you should not pass file as argument to .exe, because your file is .exe